# Class of Nullable objects

Tags: c#, class, logic, nullable

This question is more a curiosity then anything...

Say there is a class like:

```
public class Foo{
public int? x {get; set;}
public int? y {get; set;}
}
```

And somewhere in the project instances were created:

```
var foo1= new Foo
         {
           x= 1;
           y= 1;
         };

var foo2= new Foo
         {
           x= 1;
           y= 1;
         };
```

If for some reason they wanted to check to see if the equal each other and set them to `NULL` if they are and print to screen...

ex:

```
if(foo1.x == foo2.x)
   foo1.x = null;
if(foo1.y == foo2.y)
   foo1.y = null;

if(foo1 == null){
   Console.WriteLine("foo1 is NULL");
}else{
   Console.WriteLine("foo1 is not NULL");
}
```

Which would print?

The instance of foo1 exists, but all it's objects are set to `NULL`. I'm new to the concept of nullable types so this struck a curiosity in me! (My Visual Studio is on the fritz or I'd test myself)

Comment: Did you run it to see what would happen?

Comment: @Jedediah I couldn't. My Visual Studio stopped working. (as mentioned above)

Comment: If your development toolkit has stopped working, *go fix that* ;p That is more important than academic questions

Comment: @MarcGravell I am fixing it as we speak! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, foo itself is still an instantiated object, regardless of the values of its member data, so the else statement would print.

Answer (score 5):

I have two hands.  If my two hands are empty, does that mean I do not exist?

An variable's null state does not depend on any of the properties of the instance it points at.

Answer (score 0):

You will have the else exucuted `foo1 is not NULL`, the object itself is not null, but the properties are.

you can set `foo1` to null by `foo1 = null`

Answer (score 0):

`foo1` is still an instantiated object and so would not be null so `Console.WriteLine("foo1 is not NULL");` would be executed.

If you really needed `foo1 == null` to return true if x and y are null then you could override the `==` operator and the `Equals()` method.